# Query consuming CPU on DB server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My db server is is having continuous high CPU load for the past few days. While investigating this, I was looking at the currently executing requests using the query

```
SELECT session_id,
       request_id,
       Db_name(database_id),
       start_time,
       status,
       command,
       Substring(txt.TEXT, ( statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1,
       ( ( CASE statement_end_offset
       WHEN -1 THEN Datalength(txt.TEXT)
       ELSE statement_end_offset
                                                                   END
           - statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1) AS statement_text,
       wait_type,
       wait_time,
       blocking_session_id,
       percent_complete,
       cpu_time,
       reads,
       writes,
       logical_reads,
       row_count
FROM   sys.dm_exec_requests
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text([sql_handle]) AS txt
WHERE  session_id <> @@SPID
       AND session_id > 50
```

Most of the time I find that apart from the regular queries sent by application server, there are these weird S queries which seem to be consuming a decent slice of CPU time. 
e.g.

[image: Screen shot from query analyzer I took yesterday for the above query]

They do not appear on the SQL profiler. Anybody has ideas what are they and what should be done about them?

Comment: The command column tells that it is a SELECT statement. But have a look at the Statement_Text column - It just says S. Nothing else. And then look at the cpu_time, logical_reads etc. Also this S does not seem to appear in the SQL profiler. I am wondering how to debug this further.

Comment: Try capturing the whole of `txt.text`. Pretty sure your `substring` code will turn out to be at fault.

Comment: I use Derek Dieter's sp_who3 for this type of investigation. Your substring code is a bit different from his. : http://sqlserverplanet.com/dmv-queries/a-better-sp_who2-using-dmvs-sp_who3/

Comment: @sassyboy - I see you accepted my answer so I assume my guess was correct? Did you find anything special about the queries with `statement_end_offset=0`?

Comment: @MartinSmith  For the time being I havent been able to dig deep into it. After switching to txt.text, I was able to find out the query for which the substring S was showing. Thus currently I am working on reducing the load on the db server and need to finish that ASAP. Once that is done, I will dig deeper and try and find out what exactly was happening and will share the learnings. Thanks for showing me the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that if you capture the whole of `txt.text` along with `statement_start_offset`  `statement_end_offset` that you will find that there are some circumstances where the offset columns can both turn out to be `0` and so the displayed `statement_text` is truncating to only show you the first character of the `SELECT` query.

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(max); 
SET @text = 'SELECT .....';
DECLARE @statement_start_offset INT; 
SET @statement_start_offset = 0;
DECLARE @statement_end_offset INT;
SET @statement_end_offset = 0;


SELECT 
       Substring(@text, ( @statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1,
       ( ( CASE @statement_end_offset
       WHEN -1 THEN Datalength(@text)
       ELSE @statement_end_offset END
           - @statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1) AS statement_text
```

I couldn't find any indication of when `statement_end_offset` would return `0` rather than `-1` though.